# Surface in complex projective space

Tags: complex-geometry, projective-space, complex-manifolds

Let $\mathbb CP^3$ be projective space. Consider polynomial $f$ of degree $k$ satisfying $f(a \mathbb v)=a^k f(\mathbb v)$ for complex number $a$ and vector $v \in \mathbb C^4$. For example $f=xy+z^2-t^2$. Then equation $f=0$ is well defined on projective space. Let $M:=\{f=0\}$ be surface in projective space. It is 2-dimensional complex manifold. Which different manifolds (topologically) can be obtain this way ?

Next we can continue and define $M=\{f=0; g=0\}$ in projective space $\mathbb CP^4$. For example $f=x^2+y^2; g=zt+u^2$ for five variables $x,y,z,t,u$. Which different manifolds (topologically) can be obtain this way ?

My next goal is to intersect such complex manifold (treated as real 4-manifold) with real hyperplane to see what 3-manifolds can be obtained this way. Does this make sense? I started from Brieskorn manifolds and come to this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generically these are smooth [complete intersections](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Complete_intersections), and their topology is well-understood, although most of them have no simpler description than this (e.g. [K3 surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K3_surface), which occur as quartic hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{CP}^3$). Their Chern classes and cohomology are known and not hard to calculate, and only depend on the degrees of the defining equations. See, for example, [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2014/06/16/hypersurfaces-4-manifolds-and-characteristic-classes/) for the case of hypersurfaces (a single equation).

Comment: Thank you very much ! That's good news. Do you know by chance what would be the answer if we consider polynomials of shape $x \overline {y}+ y \overline {z}$ ? I am keen on checking such a polynomials on quaternion $\mathbb HP^2$.